# I’m not using the add-on, but the error is “Unable to load requested field type file: ft.wygwam.php.”

Tags: add-on, templates, fieldtype

I updated EE from 2.2.2 to 2.7 core and moved the site to a subdomain called ee.mydomain.com. I changed the URL in config.php and in Admin/General Configuration, and admin works fine.

But when I try to view a page in the template editor or the site as a whole, all I get is the error

```
"Unable to load requested field type file: ft.wygwam.php.

Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory"
```

I'm not using the Wygwam add-on and never have. The system/expressionengine/third_party folder is empty except for an index.html file.

Setting the debug flag in main site index.php shows no errors.

If it matters, I have this in .htaccess, but it makes no difference with it or without it when viewing the site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas? How can I delete references to the ft.wygwam.php file? Are they in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that WYGWAM was installed previously and still having record in database table. Check the database table "exp_fieldtypes" if having any record with field "name" as WYGWAM. You can delete that record.

Also, there may be some custom fields which may be using WYGWAM field type. You might check it also.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the "wygwam" in exp_fieldtypes, too. I also had to go to exp_channel_fields and change the instances of "wygwam" in the field_type column to "text"; this made the difference and fixed the error. I found all instances of "wygwam" with search in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed it.

Comment: I didn't need to delete any records, just change the `exp_channel_fields` `field_type` to `text`, thanks for that comment @songdogtech!